# How to create a proxy with scapy

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I would like to create a proxy using scapy to demonstrate how proxies are used in the real world. What I am trying to accomplish here is both the client sending these packets so I can examine the data being sent and have the proxy in the middle forwarding along these packets.

Ive read online here to create a script to send http requests but I would like it so send all data not just http requests. 
https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/04/29/raw-packet-manipulation-with-scapy

```
import logging 
logging.getLogger("scapy").setLevel(1)  

from scapy.all import *  

def make_test(x,y):     
    request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + y  + "\r\n"     
    p = IP(dst=x)/TCP()/request     
    out = sr1(p)     
    if out:         
        out.show() 
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    interact(mydict=globals(), mybanner="Scapy HTTP Tester")
```

Also I've seen here on how to forward traffic
[Scapy forwarding packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912854/scapy-forwarding-packages)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time
from scapy.all import sniff, sendp, ARP, Ether

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print sys.argv[0] + " <target> <spoof_ip>"
    sys.exit(0)

iface = "wlan1"
target_ip = sys.argv[1]
fake_ip = sys.argv[2]

ethernet = Ether()
arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip, psrc=fake_ip, op="is-at")
packet = ethernet / arp

while True:
    sendp(packet, iface=iface)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Is there any online guides or any scripts that already outline how to send and forward packets using scapy?

Comment: Note that the article "Raw Packet Manipulation with Scapy" mentioned in the question has moved to: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2015/04/raw-packet-manipulation-with-scapy/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a full tutorial and guide with code/examples. It is a step by step guide with good and rich information.

https://github.com/robert/how-to-build-a-tcp-proxy

Comment: You are welcome:) I would be grateful if you mark answered correct @9nr7fk